# Does primary index not work when using IN()?

Tags: mysql, indexing, subquery

```
SELECT 
  i.id 
FROM 
  itable i
WHERE 
  i.id IN (
    SELECT 
      itable_id j 
    FROM 
      ijoin j 
    WHERE 
      j.user_id = '1'
  )
```

This query examines every single row on itable, which is about 3 million.
Since i.id is the PRIMARY KEY, shouldn't it just fetch those items?

How can I optimize this query?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: It says it's running through every single row on itable and using the PRIMARY index.

Comment: This is why they invented joins.

Comment: @DMac, was more curious as to why it was happening... but yes JOINS do seem to solve the performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is notoriously poor at optimizing this type of query. Instead of selecting the small number of values in the subquery and using them to index into the main table, it iterates through all the rows in the main query and uses them to index into the table in the subquery.

It does better if you use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id
FROM itable i
JOIN ijoin j ON i.id = j.itable_id
WHERE j.user_id = '1'
```